# Javascript : I cannot access JSON objects inside an array using array index

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
database.ref().once("value", function (snap) {
    scores = snap.val();
    console.log(scores);
    console.log(scores[1]);
});
```

[image]

scores is an array of JSON objects taken from a firebase database.

However, I cannot access the objects inside the array.

I assume that `scores[1]` would print.

```
-L1qn0mBwpny-7FVzlCF : {Name: "Josh", Score: 9}
```

But it prints `undefined`.

Comment: is it  not array, this is JSON object. you can access it via `scores['-L1qn0mBwpny-7FVzlCF']`

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't print it because `scores` is a JavaScript object, and not an array. Plus, there is no key `1` in that object.

To get the underlying object of key `-L1qn0mBwpny-7FVzlCF`, you need to access it like this:

```
scores['-L1qn0mBwpny-7FVzlCF'] // { "Name": "Josh", "Score": 9 }
```

Comment: Is there a way I can iterate through this like an array. The keys are auto generated so I don't know about them?

Comment: Yes of course! Please read about [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).